# tomcat eclipse error Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at ...The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Can anyone give me some advice on this error?
Whenever I try to define a new server on eclipse by using tomcat, I get this error:

```
Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at C:\gwl\web\apache\conf. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
```

[image: this is the pic of the error]

**My Tomcat version is 8.5**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an installed copy of Tomcat. Your user does not have full ownership over its file tree, and the installation layout might have other unanticipated differences. Get a tar/zip file from Apache, or on more recent versions, let the wizard download Tomcat for you.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat must have gotten corrupted. You'll have to uninstall tomcat from your system and reinstall it using a tar version if you still want to stick with the same Tomcat version that got corrupted-or go for a higher version that has your patch fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).